# Correct way to use Logs debug in android? Breakpoint

Tags: java, android, debugging

My app is currently crashing on start I only have one class MainActivity I'm trying to figure out what causing it

I found that there is multiple Log

Log.v(); // Verbose Log.d(); // Debug Log.i(); // Info Log.w(); // Warning Log.e(); // Error

Which one should I use ? and what about Breakpoint should I check every entry method ?

I tried implementing like this I'm not sure if it's the best or right way

```
try{
  camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     openDialog();
      }
      });
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("I shouldn't be here", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the logcat stacktrace, it already should tell you what caused the exception. You should only need to set breakpoints around where the exception happens

As for which level of logging you need, it is up to you to determine the severity & verbosity of the message. Info is a general print, error is critical, warn is somewhere in between and debug is for putting lots of details. And `Log.wtf` is just for laughs  (although the actual reason is mentioned in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the default Log class, consider using [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

Remember, whenever you log in production a puppy dies. ☠️